# Keep an absolute-positioned element underneath a responsive one at all times

Tags: html, css, css-position, absolute

Ok, so what I am trying to accomplish is placing an absolute-positioned element beneath a responsive image. The issue is that, whenever the screen size changes, the image changes size and the absolute-positioned element does not stay beneath it.

Here is a code pen I've been working on and helps illustrate the issue: https://codepen.io/gojiHime/pen/MXXGbK?editors=1100

And for Stack Overflow sake, here is the CSS and HTML:

```
<div class="item">
  <div class="btn-container">
    <a href="https://www.rottentomatoes.com/" target="_blank" class="learn-more">Learn More</a>
  </div>
  <a href="https://www.doomworld.com/" class="outer-link" target="_blank" tabindex="0">
      <img src="image.png" alt="">
      <div class="cta">Download Now</div>
  </a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.item {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 1024px;
  display: block;
  height: auto;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.item a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
.item img {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.cta,
.learn-more {
  font-size: 36px;
  width: 280px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.learn-more {
  background: forestgreen;
  color: black;
  position: absolute;
  width: 280px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  top: 50%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 15px;
}

.learn-more:hover {
  background: darkgreen;
  color: white;
}

.outer-link {
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 1024px;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.cta {
  border: 1px solid orange;
  background: orange;
  color: white;
  margin-top: 8rem;
  padding: 10px;
}
.cta:hover {
  color: black;
  background: brown;
}
```

Now, The image and the "Download Now" pieces MUST be kept within the same link tag. Why not just make them separate links and put the "Learn More" button between them? Well, that wasn't my choice by I'm stuck with it so, it is what it is.

What I'd like is for the "Learn More" button to stay underneath the image at all times regardless of what size the image is. I've been trying different things but can't get it to stay below the image. I can't put it inside the link that contains the image and "Download Now" button because the "Learn More" button must have its own link.

Any ideas?

Comment: Absolute positioning means you know where you want to put the element in relation to a parent, so you won't be able to use this unless you know the height of your image. You could find out with JS, if that's an option. On the other hand, how much can you modify the structure of your HTML?

Comment: @VictoriaRuiz I can't change the fact that the image and "Download Now" have to be inside the an href tag. That's really it.

Comment: The order you placed the element in is so wrong, explains why you're having issues. consider using a background for the image instead.

Comment: Can't use the image as a background. This is how it is. It's not my decision about the way the elements are setup, and I tried changing it to something more reasonable but I was told that this is what it needs to be.

Answer (score 0):

Use flexbox and change the order of the elements and you can get rid of absolute position. You can then play with negative margin to make the button below the image:

```css
.item {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  
}

.btn-container {
  order:2;
  margin-top: -7.5rem;
}

.item a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
.item img {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.cta,
.learn-more {
  font-size: 36px;
  width: 280px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.learn-more {
  background: forestgreen;
  color: black;
  width: 280px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 15px;
}

.learn-more:hover {
  background: darkgreen;
  color: white;
}

.cta {
  border: 1px solid orange;
  background: orange;
  color: white;
  margin: 4rem auto 0;
  padding: 10px;
}
.cta:hover {
  color: black;
  background: brown;
}
```

```html
<div class="item">
  <div class="btn-container">
    <a href="https://www.rottentomatoes.com/" target="_blank" class="learn-more">Learn More</a>
  </div>
  <a href="https://www.doomworld.com/" class="outer-link" target="_blank" tabindex="0">
  <img src="http://placehold.jp/550x350.png" alt="">
  <div class="cta">Download Now</div>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: This is good but it doesn't work in smaller screens in IE 11 and things still need to look good there, too.